# Sending and receiving arrays/objects over HTTP.

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, rest

I'm working on a project that requires a shopping basket

The basket will be set up using Angular and the HTTP request containing the basket contents will be sent to a ASP MVC WebAPI.

How should the information be sent, should I encode the data in JS then decode the data in C#? Create more fields on the fly? Or am i totally missing something?

Comment: You send the data as JSON. JSON is the universal language of the internet. Whatever data you pass into the object as the body of your Post Request will be converted to JSON. When it hits your server you can decode it to suit your needs.

Comment: :( ... This is why I hate Frameworks ... We get questions like this ... But as a general rule, send the data as JSON

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try just posting your data using `$http` or `$resource` service to your web api? Architecture of WebAPI is such that it could look at the incoming requests content-type and accept headers and do the translations/decoding auto-magically